# iOS: RCTFatalException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

The application starts and immediately crashes. I check the debug console and see the following error:

```
ASI found [CoreFoundation] (sensitive) '*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly', reason: 'Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly''
```

I've already tried everything I can find and can't seem to resolve this issue.

This problem only occurs when the application is downloaded on TestFlight and then installed. When just through Xcode - everything works fine.

P.S. When you create an ipa file and install it, there will be an error too